# Create a checkboxlist of user roles MVC5 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, sqlmembershipprovider

I am trying to show a checkbox list of application roles in a view.

I am not sure how to populate view with all the roles that I pull from the aspnet_roles table.

If I use the code below I get null reference exception because ApplicationRoles is empty.

Could anyone please help me or guide me of what is the best way to achieve this?

ViewModel code is

```
 public class UserViewModel
 {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<aspnet_Roles> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
 }
```

and in controller I am trying to load them by using following code

```
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
    UserViewModel user = new UserViewModel();
    user.ApplicationRoles = db.aspnet_Roles.ToList();

    ViewBag.ApplicationRoles = new SelectList(db.aspnet_Roles.ToList(),"RoleId","RoleName");
        return View();
 }
```

In view this is

```
@using Test.Web.Models;
@model Test.Web.Models.UserViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserRole})
        <div>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ApplicationRoles.Count(); i++)
            {
                    var role = Model.ApplicationRoles[i];
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ApplicationRoles[i].RoleId)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ApplicationRoles[i].RoleId)
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicationRoles[i].RoleName)
            }
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your not returning your model to the view, so `Model.ApplicationRoles.Count()` throws an exception because `ApplicationRoles` is `null`. It needs to be  `return View(user);` in your `Create()` method

Comment: And once you correct that, it will still not work because you have `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ApplicationRoles[i].RoleId)` before `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ApplicationRoles[i].RoleId)` which means that in the POST method, you will only get back the initial value of  `RoleId` - the value of the checkboxes will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I gess your problem in this line:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < UserViewModel.ApplicationRoles.Count(); i++)
```

it should be

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ApplicationRoles.Count(); i++)
```

And in your `Controller` you should pass your `ViewModel` to `View`:

```
ViewData.Model = user;
return View();
```

Comment: Thank you I did as you suggested but still get 'System.NyllReferenceException' error